# How do you make the bottom of the error bars start on the x-axis in error.bars.by() in psych package in R?

Tags: r, errorbar, psych

In using the error.bars.by() function in the psych package in R, when  bars=TRUE, the bars are drawn incorrectly on the chart. The bars base is below the x-axis and overwrites the x-axis labels.  Does anyone know of setting, fix,  or workaround for this? I tried specifying ylim = c(1,2) but this did not help.

```
library(psych)
y <- abs(rnorm(1:100))
i <- rep(1:2, 50)
error.bars.by(y  ,  i,  bars=TRUE ) # Bottom of bars on x-axis
error.bars.by(y+1,  i,  bars=TRUE ) # Bottom of bars below x-axis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xpd` option of `barplot`:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- abs(rnorm(1:100))
i <- rep(1:2, 50)

error.bars.by(y+1,  i,  bars=TRUE, ylim=c(1, 3), xpd=FALSE)
```

[image]